# Is there a way to implement actionbar to the activity that extends youtubebaseactivity

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, android-actionbar-compat

I have an activity that extends youtubebaseActivity for playing youtube videos. i would like to have an actionbar in this activity. Is there a way to implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[YouTubePlayerFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerFragment) is designed so you can play YouTube videos and use any Activity class (such as `AppCompatActivity`):

> Using this fragment is the preferred way of playing YouTube videos because your activity does not need to extend an activity provided by the library, as is the case with using the YouTubePlayerView directly.

There's also [YouTubePlayerSupportFragment](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) if you use Support Fragments.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. With this i can easily extend actionbaractivity but when i use 'getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);' (at line 32) it shows error as   **07-18 13:23:38.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21060): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 13:23:38.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21060):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.getSupportActionBar(ActionBarActivity.java:66)
07-18 13:23:38.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21060):  at com.abc.efg.YoutubeVideoView.onCreate(YoutubeVideoView.java:32)
**

Comment: I'd suggest asking another question with the full stack trace and your code. Feel free to give a link here and I can take a look

Comment: if you convert all activity in a fragmentsupportyoutube You will run properly, I tried :) - > delete proyect and getbakcup